# Android Manifest with multiple activities and fragments are severely corrupted! How do I fix them?

Tags: java, android, manifest

Code is replaced by these kind of symbols.

```
stantValue   AlertDialog_AppCompat_Light  Animation_AppCompat_Dialog  Animation_AppCompat_DropDownUp  Animation_AppCompat_Tooltip  "Animation_Design_BottomSheetDialog  AppBaseTheme  AppTheme  AudioFileInfoOverlayText  Base_AlertDialog_AppCompat      Base_AlertDialog_AppCompat_Light 
 Base_Animation_AppCompat_Dialog  #Base_Animation_AppCompat_DropDownUp   Base_Animation_AppCompat_Tooltip
```

*Thanks!!*

Comment: Please check the same file by opening into Notepad or other Editor you have. Is it corrupted there as well or in Android Studio only?

Comment: Opened with notepad++ corrupted there as well

Comment: Then its tough to get the code back. Have you tried checking local history from android studio? may be you can get old file data from there

Comment: Is your VCS configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your code from Git history if your VCS is configured. And try to revert back to the previous commit version and do the changes manually.